# Practice to call a function inside itself

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have parent/child relation with tables. Looks like this.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField()

class ParentChild(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='child')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='parent')
    validfrom = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    validto = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I am trying to query a whole tree and create a json to send to template.
So for each person I'm thinking of using a function to query the children, and for each children use same function to query if that child has any children.

So this is my function

```
def getChildren(parentID):
    try:
        children = Person.objects.filter(parent=parentID)

        addJson = 'children: ['

        for a in children:
            addJson = addJson + '{text: { name: "Child '+str(a.id)+'" }},'
            addJson = getChildren(str(a.id))

        return addJson
    except:        
        return addJson
```

This only gets me one child then nothing more. So I'm guessing it's not possible to invoke itself, or maybe a function have to finish before being called again.

I'm pretty stuck right now. Ideas are much welcome!

Comment: But really, for a tree structure you should use something like [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/) which will be far more efficient.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I been using that in other matters. But can't seem to be able now when relation of parent/child is set to a timeframe. I only find that mptt is useful if the tree is fixed. For me ralations will change and I need to keep the history of the relations.

Comment: Your guess that it's not possible for a function to call itself is off-beam. It is very definitely possible. So the problem is with your code, not with any supposed inability to make recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I wasn't taking notice about that the query were for a PK in wrong table.

```
def getChildren(parentID, jsonData):
    try:
        qChildren = ParentChild.objects.filter(parent=parentID).values('child')

        addJson = jsonData + 'children: ['

        for a in qChildren:
            addJson = addJson + '{text: { name: "Child ' + str(a['child']) + '" }},'
            addJson = getChildren(str(a['child']), addJson)
        addJson = addJson + ']'
        return addJson
    except:
        return None
```